# How to print value from one column based on another column

Tags: python, dataframe

Can anyone help me to write a function which will print the value of output based on bukrs column
I am working with excel data which is huge so I cannot hard code the input . So I want to write a function which will help me to do that. Basically what my function should do, function should read the excel and then compare with bukers and fetch corresponding values from output column

```
    bukrs   output
0   6000    Us_600_z001
1   6003    Us_603_z001
2   6023    Us_623_z001
3   1006    Us_1006_z001
```

I tried but I am not getting the output.

`df2=df.query("bukrs==6000")["output"]`

`print(df2)`

**This is also working but the problem is there are so many rows and I cannot hard code everytime**

Comment: What do you mean by `hard code the input`? And, what is your desired input and output for the function? `string`? or `list`? or `dict` of mapping between `bukrs` and `output`? Everything is unclear. Please clarify more to make everyone understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def output(bukrs):
    output = df.loc[df['bukrs'] == bukrs, 'output'].values
    return output
```

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bukrs': [6000, 6003, 6023, 1006, 6000], 'output': ['Us_600_z001', 'Us_603_z001', 'Us_623_z001', 'Us_1006_z001', 'Us_700_z001']})

    bukrs   output
0   6000    Us_600_z001
1   6003    Us_603_z001
2   6023    Us_623_z001
3   1006    Us_1006_z001
4   6000    Us_700_z001
```

output:

```
> output(6000)
 
array(['Us_600_z001', 'Us_700_z001'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: df2=df.query("bukrs==6000")["output"]
print(df2)
This is also working but the problem is there are so many rows and I have to print the the values of "output" based on the values of "bukrs

Comment: Hi I think I was not clear with my question , here what i want to write a function such that if there is a match in column booker , corresponding value of output columns is printed

Comment: @AshutoshAnand Let see the updated version of my answer. Is that what you looking for?

Comment: this is working but the problem is I am working with excel data which is huge so I cannot hard code the input . So I want to write a function which will help me to do that. Basically what my function should do, function should read the excel and then compare with bukers and fetch corresponding values from output column

Comment: How is it different from my answer? You just add the part of reading excel, how difficult? What do you mean by `hard code the input`? Also, where is the hard code in my answer? And, what is your desired input and output for the function? `string`? or `list`? or `dict` of mapping between `bukrs` and `output`? Everything is unclear. So, this is the best solution and suggestion that I can provide, given your unclear topic, unclear problem formulation, little data example, no input example, and no expected output.